how to determine which dependencies are used in which project in nx
I am learning more about the monorepo and nx.
in nx, they by default have project.json instead of package.json and reading project.json doesn't tell much.
In this repo I am trying to understand what all repo they are using in backend
Is there a way to do it? without building? how does nx keep track of which dependency is used in which repo?
